# Advice needed regardng method exit in Python

Tags: python

I need to exit a rather long method that is executed by a thread in the event of a status change elsewhere in the "system". That change would be indicated by a boolean flag changing from False to True. I need to exit the method as though an exception had occurred. Yes, I could go in and put a bunch of "if" statements in the method and return in that fashion but I am looking for something more elegant. I could put the execution of the method in a try clause but I don't know, and cannot find, a way of having the change in the flag value trigger and exception. Maybe what I am trying to do cannot be done the way I am thinking of it.

Any ideas appreciated...

Comment: What changes the flag value? Can't that code raise an exception / do the return?

Comment: `break` or `return`? Please post example code so we can better help you

Comment: It might help if you can show some of the actual code to give us an idea of what you're doing.

Comment: I cannot show the code because we are a contractor for DoD (silly I know...). The code won't really help though. I am just looking for any ideas of how to get out of that long (too long, that I did not write), immediately as though an exception occurred. But, exiting the method is all that needs to stop. I am probably wanting something that doesn't exist.

Comment: @lee _I cannot show the code because we are a contractor for DoD (silly I know...)._ It's fine if you can't share the exact code, as long as you can provide something which illustrates the problem/situation (see [mcve]).